# No free buffer available in buffer pool

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I was trying to create a table which contains millions of data, but got the below error.

```
SQL Error: ORA-00379: no free buffers available in buffer pool DEFAULT for block size 8K

00379. 00000 -  "no free buffers available in buffer pool %s for block size %sK"
*Cause:    All buffers in the specified buffer pool for the specified block size
           are in use and no free buffers are available.
*Action:   Increase the number of buffers in the specified pool for the specified
           block size
```

How to increase the size of the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

This  is due to the insufficent buffer pool for the specified block size, all the buffer pools are utilized and you need to set some higher value for the cache to make it work.

Connect to the database instance as sys user and run the command

Alter system set db_cache__size = 8M or 16M scope=both;

Comment: If AMM (Automatic Memory Management) is in use, then you aren't supposed to set the db_8k_cache_size to anything other than 0 are you? (see below I have a related issue)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem on a large database (160 gigabytes) when running a number of queries from C# (assembling an Export).

client_result_cache_size big integer 0
db_16k_cache_size        big integer 0
db_2k_cache_size         big integer 0
db_32k_cache_size        big integer 0
db_4k_cache_size         big integer 0
db_8k_cache_size         big integer 0
db_cache_size            big integer 0
db_flash_cache_size      big integer 0
db_keep_cache_size       big integer 0
db_recycle_cache_size    big integer 0

From reading around the "0" above means that it is automatically managed by AMM (Automatic Memory Management), however seems like Oracle isn't garbage collecting during the queries.

I think the figures below show the Oracle memory in use by AMM.

memory_max_target                 big integer 2512M 
memory_target                     big integer 2512M

I don't think manually setting the memory is the answer, but what is the answer?